# Iterate over list with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a little bit new to this C++ and i wrote some code but it gave Access violation reading location....error
Here is the code

```
std::shared_ptr<Shoop> FindChips(const Scam& scan) const
{
    for each(std::shared_ptr<Shoop> pChips in mPeas)
    {
        if (pChips->GetMoreChips().Frieh(scan))
            return pChips;
    }
}
```

where mPeas is `std::list<std::shared_ptr<Shoop>>`

Please help i've been stuck with this for a while

Comment: I'm not sure that's real C++...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not real C++...

Comment: @Oli Might be the terrible Visual C++ foreach extension...

Comment: Ignoring the suspicion that this should not compile, nothing is `return`d if no match is found why should have at least emitted a warning. I am unsure what the caller would get in that case, IIRC it is undefined behaviour which might explain the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean below code, in a standard C++ ?!

```
for (auto &pChips : mPeas)
{
    if (pChips->GetMoreChips().Frieh(scan))
        return pChips;
}
return nullptr;  // <-- return nullptr and check it at caller side
```

- Where is the point of crash? Inside the `for` or after returning the function?
- Check out all items of `mPeas` are constructed by `new` or not?
- How do you use the returned object, do you check the validity of it or not?

Comment: @M M, yes. thats what i mean. Please help